# Как подставить html код в шаблон DetailView? Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, backend

У меня есть модель, в которой хранится информация про статьи на сайт, я хочу что бы в поле с текстом статьи можно было вписывать html теги. Так как эта информация должна отображаться для разных статей, но с одним шаблоном в url у меня переход на страницу прописан так:

```
path('<int:pk>', views.game_page.as_view(), name='game_page')
```

Класс game_page :

```
class game_page(DetailView):
    model = Games
    template_name = 'games/game_page.html'
    context_object_name = 'i'
```

Пока что html код при вставке с помощью {{i.main_part}} выглядит как сам код и некоторые символы по типу < > в коде страницы отображаются через &.
Помогите, как исправить?

Comment: Используйте тэг autoescape, https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/templates/builtins.html

Comment: autoescape пробовал, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
{{i.main_part|safe}}
```